# Sql query taking forever to execute

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, sql-in

Following is query that i am trying to execute and it is taking forever to execute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CLN_CLNDR_DT)FROM CLN_CLNDR CLN,
SYG_SYSTEM_GLOBALS SYG,CTD_CSH_TRNSCTN_DTLS CTD WHERE CLN.CLN_BP_ID = SYG.SYG_BP_ID AND CLN.CLN_ENTITY_ID = CTD.CTD_ENTITY_ID AND CLN_DT_SEQ_NUM  
IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT (CLN1.CLN_DT_SEQ_NUM) 
 FROM CLN_CLNDR CLN1,
 SBD_SYS_BSNS_DTS SBD,
 SYG_SYSTEM_GLOBALS SYG,
 CTD_CSH_TRNSCTN_DTLS CTR
WHERE SBD.SBD_BSNS_DT  = CLN1.CLN_CLNDR_DT
AND CLN1.OU_ID         = SBD.OU_ID
AND CLN1.CLN_BP_ID     = SYG.SYG_BP_ID
AND CLN1.CLN_ENTITY_ID = CTR.CTD_ENTITY_ID
);
```

When i try to run just the query inside **in** , it easily returns result as 
(522,470,419,417,553,582,305,361)

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CLN1.CLN_DT_SEQ_NUM) 
 FROM CLN_CLNDR CLN1,
 SBD_SYS_BSNS_DTS SBD,
 SYG_SYSTEM_GLOBALS SYG,
 CTD_CSH_TRNSCTN_DTLS CTR
WHERE SBD.SBD_BSNS_DT  = CLN1.CLN_CLNDR_DT
AND CLN1.OU_ID         = SBD.OU_ID
AND CLN1.CLN_BP_ID     = SYG.SYG_BP_ID
AND CLN1.CLN_ENTITY_ID = CTR.CTD_ENTITY_ID;
```

Also when i try to execute directly the full query replacing the query inside **in** block 
with the result of inner query that is (522,470,419,417,553,582,305,361),

It is working fine.

As i am new to this , i don't know what is going on .
Please help me with this.

Comment: It looks like the optimiser gets confused and chooses an inferior execution plan for the full query.

Could you add the execution plans of the three variants (IN part, full query and full query with IN part replaced with a constant.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what u are asking right now. Do u want us to provide u the three queries? Or something else.

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before query to get execution plan for selected query (it will show you what steps SQL want to do to execute query)

Comment: It seems the optimiser does pick an inferior plan, I think you will probably need to use hints to precisely tell which query execution to use. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm

Comment: You also shall consider replacing `FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 WHERE...` for `FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ParentId = Table1.Id...`. The list of comma separated tables is an old SQL89 standard syntax replaced in SQL92 for JOINs. We are now at SQL2011...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all the tables in the subquery since you are already using them to filter rows in the outer query. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CLN_CLNDR_DT)
FROM CLN_CLNDR CLN,
SYG_SYSTEM_GLOBALS SYG,
CTD_CSH_TRNSCTN_DTLS CTD 
WHERE CLN.CLN_BP_ID = SYG.SYG_BP_ID 
AND CLN.CLN_ENTITY_ID = CTD.CTD_ENTITY_ID 
AND CLN_DT_SEQ_NUM  
IN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT (CLN1.CLN_DT_SEQ_NUM) 
 FROM CLN_CLNDR CLN1,
 SBD_SYS_BSNS_DTS SBD,
WHERE SBD.SBD_BSNS_DT  = CLN1.CLN_CLNDR_DT
AND CLN1.OU_ID         = SBD.OU_ID
);
```

Comment: It might even be better when joining using the SQL92 syntax instead of SQL89, that is, having multiple `FROM` tables where the condition to join them is stated in the `WHERE` clause. Use `JOIN` syntax instead.